# Does WSO2 calculate SOA benefits along the time?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am studying WSO2 Governance Registry and I am impressed with all its features. However, I would like to know whether it measures SOA benefits or not.

Some other SOA Governance tools let you inform the amount of hours spent on the development of a specific service and calculate how many hours were then saved every time that service was reused. Along the time, you get the perspective of how many hours were saved by reuse thus it is possible to have an approximate amount of money that was also saved.

In summary, does WSO2 Governance Registry (or other WSO2 product) provide that feature?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Governance registry does not support this out of the box.

However, there are some roadmap items in AppFactory towards this direction.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in GReg 5.0.0 onward. Now you can create lifecycle checkpoints according to pre-defined time constrains.

Please find [this post](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-set-lifecycle-checkpointsaka.html).

hope this helps.